# Exchange 2013 & Web Apps 2013

Tags: web-applications, exchange-2013

I'm trying to configure our Exchange 2013 OWA server to be able to preview documents with Office Web Apps. Web Apps works just fine in SharePoint 2013, as well as for PowerPoint presenting in Lync 2013. Currently were using a self-signed cert for internal use only on the OWP server since Lync requires SSL for PowerPoint presenting.

Problem is whenever I try to use Web Apps within Exchange OWA, I get a message telling me that Web ready is disabled. I've enabled it within Exchange Management, and also pointed Exchange at the Web App discovery URL. No matter what I try I seem to get the same disabled message. Event logs are clean on both exchange and web app servers so I'm kind of at a loss on how to proceed.
 Has anyone else dealt with this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebReady and OWAS are two different things-- WebReady is what Exchange 2007/2010 used for document rendering, and 2013 can use it for non-Office documents. It looks like this is a semi-known problem (e.g. http://www.brainlitter.com/2013/02/10/fix-for-the-webready-document-viewing-service-has-been-disabled-by-the-administrator-for-your-organization/), so I'd suggest making sure that you have the right WAC endpoint and vdir settings, then check and uncheck the WebReady settings and then do an iisreset.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/99011e88-e4ed-4c73-93da-544b817de2c5/error-the-webready-document-viewing-service-has-been-disabled-by-the-administrator-for-your?forum=exchangesvrclients also points out that you should be seeing event IDs 140 and 142 if WAC integration is successful. Do you see any WAC-related erors in your event log?

Comment: I got this working some time ago. At some point the Exchange server lost the settings that connected it to our Lync environment, so we also lost user presence. I repaired that, and low and behold I could open documents through web apps again. Not sure how these two are related but that was this fix. Marking your answer as correct since the second paragraph helped me verify that it was indeed working.